# Can somebody explain clearly what is different between 'draw' and 'pull'

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning, difference

Can somebody explain clearly what is the difference between 'draw' and 'pull'. In the excerpt below, if I change 'drew back' to 'pull back', Google gives different meanings. If I change 'pull together' to 'draw together' Google translates them the same. Such verbs come across in any text very often. What do I need to know when I can replace these verbs without losing meaning and when I can't? I have learned to translate them, but I can hardly use them correctly in English.

> Canute **drew his hand** back from the latch as though it were red hot. He
>   was not the kind of man to make a good eavesdropper, and he wished he
>   had knocked sooner. He **pulled himself together** and struck the door
>   like a battering ram. Mary jumped and opened it with a screech.

Here is the other example. What does 'drawing out' mean or would 'pulling out' mean? By the way I can 't find a suitable translation for '**power of drawing
out the social side**'. What does it mean?

> But he was not a social man by nature and had not the power of **drawing
>   out** the social side of other people.

On the Divide
by Willa Cather

Comment: Consider this: It is implied it was easy to with**draw**  his hand, but harder to **pull** himself together (gather his resolve to act). Also try exchanging one word for the other and rereading it.

Answer (score 1):

'draw' implies action with little or no resistance.
 'pull' is to apply force (toward ones' self), implying it takes effort.

Similar in meaning. The context in which they are used together would define the difference.
"You can draw your own conclusions here, if you can manage to pull the notion of their complexity from your thoughts"

Comment: What would you say about phrasal verbs using these verbs?

Comment: This is very context dependent. I agree in OP's example if you said Canute "pulled his hand back" it would imply there was some resistance to that action (and "drew his hand back" doesn't imply that). But when you "draw wire" (stretch out a metal to form it into a wire) you would expect there to be substantial resistance.

Comment: @ThePhoton Certainly a good example of an exception to the rule. I will look for the origin to that.

Comment: @Vitaly I would need to see an example first. I am not that sharp minded.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer saying that in the case of *drawing back his hand*, the use of *draw* implies less effort than would *pull*. But this is very context dependent, and I think in your other example, using *draw* implies effort.

> By the way I can 't find a suitable translation for 'power of drawing out the social side'. What does it mean?

Here, *power* means ability. And *drawing out* something from other people means leading or convincing them to do something. So the overall meaning is that "he" was not capable of leading other people to act sociably.

You probably know some people who can start a conversation with any stranger, even a bad-tempered one, and quickly convince the stranger to act friendly toward them. The quoted sentence is saying that "he" isn't one of those people.

In this case I'd say that the use of the term *draw* is meant to imply some effort is involved in this process (as in [drawing wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_drawing)). It implies that the other person isn't initially inclined to act sociably. In this case *pull* couldn't be substituted without breaking the idiom.

For the most part, *draw* as a synonym for *pull* is obsolete in today's English and is only used in a few idiomatic cases, rather than as a word that can be used wherever its meaning fits.

Comment: I understand in general. Here's just what idiom do you mean from your words: "In this case pull couldn't be substituted without breaking the idiom."?

Comment: @Vitaly, It means that "draw [something] out of someone" is an idiom, and we always use *draw* in this idiom and not *pull*.